# Align algorithm lines on the equals/assignment symbol

Tags: algorithms, alignment, algorithm2e

I wish to align lines on my algorithm on a certain symbol. For instance:

```
long_variable_name = k | long_variable_name = k
variable = l           | variable           = l
```

In terms of LaTeX I have the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}


% ALGORITHM PARAMETERS %
\SetAlFnt{\small\fontfamily{cmr}}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\LinesNumbered
\IncMargin{1em}

\begin{algorithm}
    \footnotesize
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwData{VARA}{VAR$_{old}$}
    \SetKwData{VARB}{VAR$_{new}$}
    \SetKwData{TEMP}{tmp$_{cc}$}
    
    \Input{ A matrix N$\times$M}
    \Output{ A number K}
   
        \BlankLine
    
        \VARA  \ := \ 123 \\
        \VARB  \ := \ 123 \\
        \TEMP  \ := \ 423 \\
    
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

And I wish to align the lines where `VARA` `VARB` and `TEMP` are assigned their values on the `:=` symbol. Is is possible to do so? Thank you in advance

#### P.S.:

Here's the output of the code

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use eqparbox, this needs two compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}


% ALGORITHM PARAMETERS %
\SetAlFnt{\small\fontfamily{cmr}}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\LinesNumbered
\IncMargin{1em}

\begin{algorithm}
    \footnotesize
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwData{VARA}{\eqmakebox[var][l]{VAR$_{\mathit{old}}$}}
    \SetKwData{VARB}{\eqmakebox[var][l]{VAR$_{\mathit{new}}$}}
    \SetKwData{TEMP}{\eqmakebox[var][l]{tmp$_{\mathit{cc}}$}}
    
    \Input{ A matrix N$\times$M}
    \Output{ A number K}

        \BlankLine

        \VARA  \ := \ 123 \\
        \VARB  \ := \ 123 \\
        \TEMP  \ := \ 423 \\

\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

[image]